# Authenticating a Xamarin.Forms-Client at a ASP.NET MVC Server with SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, signalr

I have created a new ASP.NET MVC project and by default it appears to use a .mdf-databasefile for authentification.

I would like to authenticate my Xamarin (Xamarin.Forms) client. The reason for this is that I would like to use the `[Authorize]` attribute later on in my SignalR hub.

**What I would like to know now:**

What exactly do I have to do to authenticate my client?
Do I have to do it in one of my hubs methods? And what classes do I have to access / call using my name & password for this purpose?
Or are my thoughts completely wrong and I have to do it in a completely different way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't authenticate directly in your hubs. I would first authenticate and then allow the hubs to be reached. To do this securely, I'd do something like this:

1. Create a Web API service to authenticate against a database, for example.
2. Make the client pre-hash the password.
3. Send a HtppRequest to the Web API login service, sending username and pre-hashed password.
4. Make the login method finish the hashing of the password using information from the database and authenticate the user.
5. Assign some secure token to that user, and send that back to the client (through HTTPS, if possible)
6. Make a custom authorize attribute, so you can check against the security token.
7. Mark the hub classes with your new [Authorize].

This is at least an idea of how you can get this done securely. For the double hashing of the password, we use a combination of `SHA512CryptoServiceProvider`, `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` and `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`.

Comment: Hey man. Thank you for the very quick response and the advice. Since I'm haven't used ASP.NET (MVC) alot yet, I am not sure, what exactly you mean with WebAPI Service? Do you mean adding a new Controller which derives from ApiController? The reason why I wanted to use ASP.NET MVC over a console server is that I can use Context.User.Identity in my SignalR hub. Will that still work, even if I use your custom authentification?

Comment: To be a bit more specific: I am pretty sure I understand the idea now, but I still am not sure, what I need to override to have my Context.User.Property point at the custom authorized user.

Comment: @Jannik, sorry for the delay in answering. Yes, a Web API service is a Controller that derives from ApiController. You will have to add the NuGet packages for ASP.NET Web API for this to work. And Identity works through ASP.NET WebForms, MVC, Web API, SignalR, etc. You can create a custom Login and pass it the security token, and you will have Context.User available right afterwards.

Comment: Alright, I will try it when I am home. I am still struggling with the "custom login and pass it the security token", do you have any example, I would love to see, what methods and classes I do need to override/use/implement.

Comment: I cannot give you an example right now since I don't have the solution with me, but what you need to do is create a custom Authorize attribute and make a function that takes the username and security token to "log in" the user. An example of a security token would be GUID generated upon validating the username and pre-hashed password, stored in a database and sent to the client.

Comment: Okay, but I feel like I have to hook into some sort of method, which gives me back the right Context.User, based on what security token the user has given me. Isn't that right?

Comment: @Jannik yes, that's right. To do that you need to login the user, that's why you need to override something like PasswordLoginAsync in a custom UserManager class. This might not be the easiest way, but it's, I think, the most powerful and secure.

Comment: So, I started implementing it yesterday. I created a new ApiController, which basically calls a method, which checks name and password using a dbcontext or (if existant) a caching dictionary. If all is correct, it returns a new object of a class, which includes a (just for testing purposes) simple security token (basically name|passwordhash). But I am struggling with the actual call of the controller now. Do you have any example code on how to call the ApiController from my existing AccountController?

Comment: Is RestSharp the right way to go? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826359/Consuming-ASP-NET-WEB-API-using-ASP-NET-MVC-and-Re

Comment: I haven't used RestSharp, so I couldn't tell you. The ApiController should be contacted through HttpWebRequest from your client to perform the login. The actual [Authorize] implementation should be done through a custom AuthorizeAttribute that would then decorate your hubs.

Comment: And where do I store the SecurityToken? I will get back the token as a json. But how do I get it back to the server every time I call my hub? Is there somehting like a cookie container / header in SignalR, where I can store it and later on access it in my Authorize-attribute? And do I need two custom Authorize attributes? One for my SignalR Connection, one for the asp.net website itself?

Comment: I'd store the Security token in the database and retrieve the value when needed. You will need one for your SignalR hubs, if you need another for the website that's another topic, however, you should keep the different authorization rules in different attributes.

Comment: "I'd store the Security token in the database and retrieve the value when needed" But I thought the client needs to have the security token? How else would the server know, what client currently is calling a hub method. Now I am totally confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97995/discussion-between-cfrozendeath-and-jannik).